# RAW HTML displayed after redirect

Tags: php

When this function is executed and the user is redirected, raw HTML is displayed on the page. It must be noted that this is not happening every time the user is redirected, it happens about 1 out of 20 times. The frequency doesn't make much sense to me.

Not only is there HTML on the page but the HTML block is outputted at random places.

```
function do_something() {
    try {
        header('Location: /pages/something');
    } catch (Exception $DB_Error) {
        echo 'There is a problem';
    }
}
```

I can't imagine this has to do with there not being an exit; after the redirect.

Could this be the clients browser? They are using Chrome and I'm thinking they might have an issue with the browser. Maybe a app/extension causing this.

Comment: When do you call your `do_something()` function?

Comment: It's a procedural call, so it's called above in the script when a $_POST variable is found.

Comment: I would add a `die();` after the redirect, so nothing else is processed.

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely the browser is causing the issue. Unfortunately, what you've provided is not enough information to reproduce the problem.